# session.getAttribute returns null on disabling cookies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Can anyone please tell me why `request.getSession().getAttribute(SESSIONUSER)` returns null when i disable cookies?

I also can't understand that here

```
Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
Cookie thisCookie = cookies[0];
int age = thisCookie.getMaxAge();  
System.out.println(age);
```

`age` comes out to be `-1` still the session expires after 10 hours or so? Why is this so?

Comment: Well i mistakenly wrote var instead of int now i have corrected it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your HTTPSession is tracked using jsessionid. It is maintained in a cookie. So when the client is sending the second request to the server, it is expected to send the jsessionid. Or else, Server cannot track the session. In short, your session is created during request.getSession() freshly everytime. Therefore, you don't see your any objects in it.

What "-1" means:
This means the the cookie should be alive till the browser is closed. If it is there for 10hrs it means your browser is not closed for 10hours.

Comment: But it expires after 10 hrs although the browser is not closed.

Comment: It means that the container is not adherent to JSR (which is very unlikely). Read the javadoc of setMaxAge() at http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setMaxAge%28int%29

Comment: The container i am using is Weblogic server. I want to determine when exactly the session will expire so that i can handle my code(ajax calls which gets whole jsp in response).Which otherwise gets login page in response when the session expires. Please let me know!

Comment: I think it needs separate question with appropriate code-snippets. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I am ready to give you all the code-snippets you want. Please help me in knowing the answer.